# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting the error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number" when I try to run this query:

```
<?php
include "../config/c_config.php";
$db = dbConn::getConnection();

$pmuid = $_POST['txtuid'];
$pnml = $_POST['txtnm'];
$ptgll = $_POST['txttgl'];
$jk = $_POST['optjk'];
$palamat = $_POST['txtalamat'];
$idv = $_POST['cbprov'];
$idc = $_POST['cbcity'];
$pkode = $_POST['txtkodepos'];
$pphone= $_POST['txtnophone'];
$pemkof= $_POST['txtmailinf'];
$pimg = $_POST['fileimg'];
$pdate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// Update data on mysql
$sqlep = "UPDATE str_user_mamber_profile SET
profile_nama_lengkap=:pnml,
profile_jk=:jk,
profile_tgl_lahir=:ptgll,
profile_alamat=:palamat,
id_provinsi=:idv,
id_city=:idc,
profile_kodepos=:pkode,
profile_phone=:pphone,
profile_email_konfirmasi=:pemkof,
profile_date=:pdate 
WHERE mamber_unique_id = :pmuid";

$qep = $db->prepare($sqlep);
$qep->execute(array(":pnml"=>$pnml,
                    ":jk"=>$jk,
                    ":ptgll"=>$ptgll,
                    ":palamat"=>$palamat,
                    ":idv"=>$idv,
                    ":idc"=>$idc,
                    ":pkode"=>$pkode,
                    ":pphone"=>$pphone,
                    ":pemkof"=>$pemkof,
                    ":pdate"=>$pdate,
                    ":pmuid"=>$pmuid));
if($qep){
    echo 'work';
}else{
    echo 'not work';
}
?>
```

after i run,this query give a result "WORK" but not update the db. i try search same question about this error but not help me to fixed. can you help me see what is wrong with the query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

change

```
":pnml"=>$pnml,
```

to

```
"pnml"=>$pnml,
```

everywhere in "execute" method

```
$qep->execute(array("pnml"=>$pnml,
                    "jk"=>$jk,
                    "ptgll"=>$ptgll,
                    "palamat"=>$palamat,
                    "idv"=>$idv,
                    "idc"=>$idc,
                    "pkode"=>$pkode,
                    "pphone"=>$pphone,
                    "pemkof"=>$pemkof,
                    "pdate"=>$pdate,
                    "pmuid"=>$pmuid));
```

Comment: @chris85 Named parameter binding is supported: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @chris85 Why you down my answer if you don't know how does it work?

Comment: I didn't down your answer, I asked a question about it. Your answer as far as I can tell doesn't have any down votes.

Comment: @chris85, thanks .. but i don't see any change in database, i'm so confused.

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah This is John's answer not mine. I'm going to delete my comment since it is irrelevant to the thread.

Comment: @johnV, sory. mistakenly written. thanks .. but i not see any change in database.

Answer (score 0):

`$qep` is a statement object, and will always be truthy. You need to capture the **result** of executing the statement:

```
$result = $qep->execute(...);
if ($result){
    echo 'work';
} else {
    echo 'not work';
    var_dump($qep->errorInfo());
}
```

Using `$_POST` values without checking that they are set may give you lots of warnings, as well.

Comment: thanks.. i getting this  warning. array(3) {undefined: [2], 00000: [1]} 00000: [1]
0: 1
undefined: [2]
0: 2 what this means?

Comment: i have capture the result